# Efficient way to iterate over rows and columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `Bg` that was created by taking `sample` in rows and `r` for in columns. `r` is a list of genes that I want to split in a row-wise manner for the entire dataframe.
My code below is taking a long time to run and repeatedly crash. I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to achieve the aim.

```
import pandas as pd

Bg = pd.DataFrame()

for idx, r in pathway_genes.itertuples():
  for i, p in enumerate(M.index):
    if idx == p:
      for genes, samples in common_mrna.iterrows():
        b = pd.DataFrame({r:samples})        
        Bg = Bg.append(b).fillna(0)
```

`M.index`

```
M.index = ['KEGG_VASOPRESSIN_REGULATED_WATER_REABSORPTION',
       'KEGG_DRUG_METABOLISM_OTHER_ENZYMES', 'KEGG_PEROXISOME',
       'KEGG_LONG_TERM_POTENTIATION', 'KEGG_ADHERENS_JUNCTION', 'KEGG_ALANINE_ASPARTATE_AND_GLUTAMATE_METABOLISM']
```

`pathway_genes`

|  | geneSymbols |
| --- | --- |
| KEGG_ABC_TRANSPORTERS | `['ABCA1', 'ABCA10', 'ABCA12']` |
| KEGG_ACUTE_MYELOID_LEUKEMIA | `['AKT1', 'AKT2', 'AKT3', 'ARAF']` |
| KEGG_ADHERENS_JUNCTION | `['ACP1', 'ACTB', 'ACTG1', 'ACTN1', 'ACTN2']` |
| KEGG_ADIPOCYTOKINE_SIGNALING_PATHWAY | `['ACACB', 'ACSL1', 'ACSL3', 'ACSL4', 'ACSL5']` |
| KEGG_ALANINE_ASPARTATE_AND_GLUTAMATE_METABOLISM | `['ABAT', 'ACY3', 'ADSL', 'ADSS1', 'ADSS2']` |

`common_mrna`

```
common_mrna = pd.DataFrame([[1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5], [1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9], [2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3], [2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7], [2.8,2.9,3.0,3.1],[3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5],[3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9],[4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3],[4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7],[4.8,4.9,5.0,5.1],[5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5],[5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9],[6.0,6.1,6.2,6.3],[6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7],[6.8,6.9,7.0,7.1],[7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5],[7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9]], columns=['TCGA-02-0033-01', 'TCGA-02-2470-01', 'TCGA-02-2483-01', 'TCGA-06-0124-01'], index =['ABCA1','ABCA10','ABCA12','AKT1','AKT2','AKT3','ARAF','ACP1','ACTB','ACTG1','ACTN1','ACTN2','ABAT','ACY3','ADSL','ADSS1','ADSS2'])
```

Desired output:

```
Bg = pd.DataFrame([[4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3],[4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7],[4.8,4.9,5.0,5.1],[5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5],[5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9],[6.0,6.1,6.2,6.3],[6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7],[6.8,6.9,7.0,7.1],[7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5],[7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9]], columns=['TCGA-02-0033-01', 'TCGA-02-2470-01', 'TCGA-02-2483-01', 'TCGA-06-0124-01'], index =['ACP1','ACTB','ACTG1','ACTN1','ACTN2','ABAT','ACY3','ADSL','ADSS1','ADSS2'])
```

Comment: please provide a single code with constructors for all the inputs (so that one just needs to copy/paste and run to reproduce your data)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! If it's ok with you, could you please double-check if your all your dataframe is aligned and correct?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew The dataframes are correct. However, the `geneSymbols` in `pathway_genes` df are lists and I'm unable to put it in a single code.

Comment: Thanks for improving the format, so to clarify, you are trying to match the pathway_genes with the common_mrna dataframe based on the lists of index from the pathway_genes? And your pathway_genes is a dictionary?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew yes, that is correct!

Comment: Ok, just one more thing, I think you have three indexes in M_index that match the `pathway_genes`?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew you are right. I removed one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, you can use list comprehension to match the `M_index` with the `pathway_genes`

```
pathway_genes = {'KEGG_ABC_TRANSPORTERS': ['ABCA1', 'ABCA10', 'ABCA12'], 'KEGG_ACUTE_MYELOID_LEUKEMIA': ['AKT1', 'AKT2', 'AKT3', 'ARAF'], 'KEGG_ADHERENS_JUNCTION': ['ACP1', 'ACTB', 'ACTG1', 'ACTN1', 'ACTN2'], 'KEGG_ADIPOCYTOKINE_SIGNALING_PATHWAY': ['ACACB', 'ACSL1', 'ACSL3', 'ACSL4', 'ACSL5'], 'KEGG_ALANINE_ASPARTATE_AND_GLUTAMATE_METABOLISM': ['ABAT', 'ACY3', 'ADSL', 'ADSS1', 'ADSS2']}

matched_index_symbols = [pathway_genes[i] for i in pathway_genes.keys() if i in M_index]
```

After that, you can use `loc` to match all the symbols.

```
flatten_list = [j for sub in matched_index_symbols for j in sub]

Bg = common_mrna.loc[flatten_list]
Out[26]: 
        TCGA-02-0033-01  TCGA-02-2470-01  TCGA-02-2483-01  TCGA-06-0124-01
ABCA1               1.2              1.3              1.4              1.5
ABCA10              1.6              1.7              1.8              1.9
ABCA12              2.0              2.1              2.2              2.3
ACP1                4.0              4.1              4.2              4.3
ACTB                4.4              4.5              4.6              4.7
ACTG1               4.8              4.9              5.0              5.1
ACTN1               5.2              5.3              5.4              5.5
ACTN2               5.6              5.7              5.8              5.9
ABAT                6.0              6.1              6.2              6.3
ACY3                6.4              6.5              6.6              6.7
ADSL                6.8              6.9              7.0              7.1
ADSS1               7.2              7.3              7.4              7.5
ADSS2               7.6              7.7              7.8              7.9
```

### Update

It seems that your `pathway_genes` is not originally a dictionary but a dataframe. If that's the case, you can extract the column index of the dataframe.

```
pathway_genes
Out[46]: 
                                                                      geneSymbols
KEGG_ABC_TRANSPORTERS                                        [ABCA1, ABCA10, ABCA12]
KEGG_ACUTE_MYELOID_LEUKEMIA                                 [AKT1, AKT2, AKT3, ARAF]
KEGG_ADHERENS_JUNCTION                             [ACP1, ACTB, ACTG1, ACTN1, ACTN2]
KEGG_ADIPOCYTOKINE_SIGNALING_PATHWAY             [ACACB, ACSL1, ACSL3, ACSL4, ACSL5]
KEGG_ALANINE_ASPARTATE_AND_GLUTAMATE_METABOLISM     [ABAT, ACY3, ADSL, ADSS1, ADSS2]

matched_index_symbols = np.array([pathway_genes['geneSymbols'].loc[i] for i in pathway_genes.index if i in M_index])

flatten_list = matched_index_symbols.ravel()
```

Comment: Also, please avoid using enumerate if you are not using the indexes for every loop generated.

Comment: `dictionary` is `pathway_genes`?

Comment: The code fails when I call the index of `M` df as `M.index` using `symbols = [pathway_genes[i] for i in pathway_genes.keys() if i in list(M.index)]`. It returns an empty `symbols` variable.

Comment: Is your M.index the same list as you have provided in your question?

Comment: Yes. It looks something like this `Index(['KEGG_VASOPRESSIN_REGULATED_WATER_REABSORPTION',
       'KEGG_DRUG_METABOLISM_OTHER_ENZYMES', 'KEGG_PEROXISOME',
       'KEGG_LONG_TERM_POTENTIATION',
       'KEGG_CYSTEINE_AND_METHIONINE_METABOLISM',
       'KEGG_AMINO_SUGAR_AND_NUCLEOTIDE_SUGAR_METABOLISM',
       'KEGG_NOTCH_SIGNALING_PATHWAY', 'KEGG_FATTY_ACID_METABOLISM',
       'KEGG_LONG_TERM_DEPRESSION', 'KEGG_CITRATE_CYCLE_TCA_CYCLE',
      dtype='object', name='NAME', length=134)`

Comment: The `idx == p` in my for loop prints values so I'm not sure why it returns an empty list with your code.

Comment: When I look at your `pathway_genes`, you are using dataframe, not dictionary. `itertuples` is a function for dataframe. If possible, can you update your `pathway_genes` in the question to the dataframe?

Comment: I'm unable to update `pathway_genes` because StackOverflow doesn't allow me to create a pandas dataframe markdown if the column values are list of lists.

Comment: It is still returning an empty `Bg`. I want to loop over the flattened list and if any of the strings match `M.index`, I want to store in `Bg` that string and all the strings after it. Otherwise, `Bg` will always be empty because `M.index` is only one string whereas the flattened object is a list of lists. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes I can understand your problem, sorry I think my format of the `pathway_genes` is not following your one previously. Now try the new updated one. Please let me know if the dataframe I have created is the same format and arrangements as yours?

Comment: Yes same format. Still returning empty `Bg`

Comment: Let's break down one by one, did you get any result for your `symbols` now? If possible, please also include a sample of your file to be accessed. I guess the culprit for the empty `Bg` is to do with the dataframe that you have provided in your question has slight different arrangement with your csv file.